# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list but the value is there in the list

Tags: python

I am new to the world of Software Engineering and I am starting at codeacademy. could someone help me understand why I get a value error here? my list shows that that value is there but I can't seem to remove it.

````
subjects = ["physics", "calculus", "poetry", "history"]
grades = [98, 97, 85, 88]

gradebook = [["physics",    98], ["calculus",   97], ["poetry", 85], ["history",    88]]

gradebook.append(["computer science", 100])
gradebook.append(["visual arts", 93])
gradebook[-1][-1] = 98
print(gradebook)
gradebook.remove(85)```
````

Comment: Did you mean `gradebook.remove(["poetry", 85])`?

Comment: `gradebook` does not contain the value `85` - all its elements are _lists_, not integers.

Comment: no i meant to remove the 85 integer by itself and I thought I was able to do that. The problem was to remove the 85 then later input a different value in that area. Am I able to do that or was it a possible misinput somewhere in the code or a possible bug in the codeacademy problem itself?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the actual codeacademy task it is hard to tell how the solution should be designed.

I found a [codeacademy forum post](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/python-gradebook/577292) discussing these instructions, which index into the sublist and remove the value via `gradebook[2].remove(85)`

Detailed explanation:

- `gradebook` is a list of lists
- `gradebook[2]` accesses the 3. element in the gradebook, i.e. the (sub)list `["poetry", 85]`
- `.remove(85)` removes the value `85` from that (sub)list.
- Afterwards, the (sub)list is only `["poetry"]`